# Como inserir um data table no banco de dados?

Tags: c#

Pessoal ja tenho meu dataTable preenchido com os valores que vieram de um arquivo .csv agora preciso inserir no banco de dados sem usar SQLBulkCopy...como fazer ? via c#

Esse metodo preenche meu dataTable:

```
public DataTable RetornaDtPreenchido(string caminho){
    DataTable dt = CriaDataTable();
    using (StreamReader arquivo = new StreamReader(caminho)){
    string linhaArquivo;
    string[] campos;
    DataRow registro;
    bool cabecalhoJaLido = false;

        while (!arquivo.EndOfStream){

            linhaArquivo = arquivo.ReadLine();

        if (!cabecalhoJaLido){
            cabecalhoJaLido = true;
            continue;
        }

            campos = linhaArquivo.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            registro = dt.NewRow();

            try{
                bool resultNumero;
                int numero;

                resultNumero = int.TryParse(campos[4], out numero);
                registro["Numero"] = numero;

                if (!resultNumero){
                    Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label1.Text = "Campo numero não esta vindo como valor inteiro";
                }

                bool resultTipoPessoa;
                int tipoPessoa;

                resultTipoPessoa = int.TryParse(campos[2], out tipoPessoa);
                registro["TipoPessoa"] = tipoPessoa;

                if (!resultTipoPessoa || tipoPessoa > 1){
                    Label2.Visible = true;
                    Label2.Text = "Campo Tipo Pessoa com valor inválido";
                }

                bool resultEstado;
                int estado;

                resultEstado = int.TryParse(campos[7], out estado);
                registro["Estado"] = estado;

                if (!resultEstado || RetornaListaEstado(estado) == false){
                    Label3.Visible = true;
                    Label3.Text = "Campo Codigo Estado não é válido";
                }

                if (campos[0].Length > 70){
                    registro["Nome"] = "";
                    Label4.Visible = true;
                    Label4.Text = "Campo Nome excedendo limite de caracteres";
                }else{
                    registro["Nome"] = campos[0].ToString().Trim();
                }

                if (fgCpfCheck(campos[1]) == false){
                    registro["Documento"] = "";
                    Label5.Visible = true;
                    Label5.Text = "CPF Inválido";
                }else{
                    registro["Documento"] = campos[1].Trim().ToString();
                }

                if (campos[3].Length > 100){
                    registro["Endereco"] = "";
                    Label6.Visible = true;
                    Label6.Text = "Campo Endereco excedendo limite de caracteres";
                }else{
                    registro["Endereco"] = campos[3].Trim().ToString();
                }

                if (campos[5].Length > 20){
                    registro["Complemento"] = "";
                    Label7.Visible = true;
                    Label7.Text = "Campo Complemento excedendo limite de caracteres";
                }else{
                    registro["Complemento"] = campos[5].Trim().ToString();
                }

                if (campos[6].Length > 60){
                    registro["Bairro"] = "";
                    Label8.Visible = true;
                    Label8.Text = "Campo Bairro excedendo limite de caracteres";
                }else{
                    registro["Bairro"] = campos[6].Trim().ToString();
                }

                if (campos[8].Length > 100){
                    registro["Cidade"] = "";
                    Label9.Visible = true;
                    Label9.Text = "Campo Cidade excedendo limite de caracteres";
                }else{
                    registro["Cidade"] = campos[8].Trim().ToString();
                }

                if (campos[9].Length > 10){
                    registro["CEP"] = "";
                    Label10.Visible = true;
                    Label10.Text = "Campo CEP excedendo limite de caracteres";
                }
                {
                    registro["CEP"] = campos[9].Trim().ToString();
                }

                if (Label2.Visible == false && Label3.Visible == false){
                    dt.Rows.Add(registro);
                }else{
                    Label11.Visible = true;
                    Label11.Text = "Operação não realizada!";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo de código pronto pra colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: ta ai editado o dt eu tenho certinho ja so preciso joga ele no banco ou se o campo CPF for repetido tem que atualiza ao inves de inserir entendeu @Cigano Morrison Mendez ?

Comment: Certo. Entendi. Você quer verificar a repetição a nível de banco ou a nível do seu `StreamReader`?

Comment: a nivel de banco...se o cpf vindo do meu registro StreamReader ja existir no banco...esse registro nao deve ser inserido e sim deve dar um update nesse cara que ta no banco

Comment: Isso seria o caso de mais uma dúvida dentro da sua pergunta, mas acredito que uma consulta trazendo um DataSet que possa ser convertido em um `Dictionary` seria o caminho.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tô um tanto enferrujado com relação a isso, mas uma dobradinha de [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) com [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) pode ser uma mão na roda.

Qualquer coisa do tipo:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = foo /*assumindo que foo é uma conexão pronta*/)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = bar /*monta um SqlCommand com o SELECT relevante. Vale SELECT * FROM tuaTabela, por exemplo.*/)
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command, connection))
        {
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.fill(dt); // dt vazio aqui, ok?
            /* aqui você preenche a tabela */
            adapter.Update(dt); // Só felicidade agora.
        }
    }
}
```

Os *Data Adapters* (tem outros além do pra SQL, todos filho de System.Data.DbDataAdapter) são componentes que preenchem uma tabela ou dataset com base no retorno do banco.

Acontece que a tabela/dataset e o *Data Adapter* têm eventos que são capturados e atentidos pelo *Command Builder*. Daí o builder vai gerando os comandos `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE` correspondentes ao que você andou fazendo na tabela automaticamente.

Quando você chama o método `Update` do *Data Adapter*, ele pega os comandos com o builder e os executa no banco de dados. No seu caso praticamente todos os comandos vão ser `INSERT`. O legal é que se a tabela já viesse preenchida, toda alteração que você fizesse na *DataTable* poderia ser facilmente aplicada também no banco de dados dessa forma :)